# Cannot complete "Ads" Section

Tags: android, publishing, google-console-developer

In the area of "Let us know whether your app contains ads" in App Content, this section tells me that I have to complete the next section

> You must let us know whether your app contains ads. The 'Contains ads' label is shown next to apps with ads on Google Play. Make sure this information is accurate, and is kept up to date. 
>   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq8az.png)

But when I go to the option, it just show me
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW9cS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, it was the Ad Blocker. I disabled my adblocker and refreshed the page and it worked.

@Mate Farkas's answer (worked on phone) inspired me to test this.

Comment: Yeah, google support told me this was a possibility, and I think that was the primary problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to complete the section on your phone.

I'm chasing the same issue for an hour now. On Chrome+MacOS I'm seeing the same error as you, on Chrome+Android (Pixel 2) it works for me.

Comment: This gave me a lead to the solution of my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading Chrome to see if the problem was the browser (I was using Edge Chromium), and the option appear, seems like is a bug with Edge Chromium.